# run rake task from crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Ubuntu, I try run my rake task from cron
My rake task:

```
namespase :import do
   task :import_twitter => :environment do
      puts "Twitter importing...." 
   end
end
```

schedule.rb file

```
every 1.minutes do
  rake "import:import_twitter", :output => {:error => 'error.log', :standard => 'cron.log'}
end
```

with whenever I generate crontab task

```
 # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/administrator/www/my_application/config/schedule.rb
    PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

    * * * * * cd /home/administrator/www/my_application && RAILS_ENV=production /usr/bin/env rake import:import_twitter >> cron.log 2>> error.log


# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/administrator/www/my_application/config/schedule.rb
```

In crontab error.log I have

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:340:in `bin_path': can't find executable rake for rake-0.8.7 (Gem::Exception)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

But when I run this task from console it work

```
path_to_my_project >rake  import:import_twitter
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue with rvm and whenever. If I want it's works I define the HOME VARIABLE and comment the PATH variable and it's works.

I thinks it's a rvm issue with loading of your environment.

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: supermarmite
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOME=/var/rails/supermarmite
#PATH=/var/rails/supermarmite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/var/rails/supermarmite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin:/var/rails/supermarmite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/var/rails/supermarmite/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/mongodb/bin

0 * * * * source ~/.bashrc && cd /var/rails/supermarmite/site/releases/20100930044915 && RAILS_ENV=production rake -s evaluate_notify

# End Whenever generated tasks for: supermarmite
```

Comment: Please write example how u wrote